# set up the probability for this problem

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having difficulty trying to set up the probability for this problem.

> If you place a \$1 bet on a number of a roulette wheel, then either you win \$35, with probability 1/38, or you lose \$1, with probability 37/38. 
>   Let X denote your gain on a bet of this type

The probability that you will be winning after 1000 bets

Solution: approximately 0.39.

I understand that central limit theorem is to be used. However, I'm unsure where to go from here.

$$ \begin{align} E[X] &= -1*\frac{37}{38} + 35*\frac{1}{38} = -\frac{1}{19} \\  
Var(X) &= (-1+\frac{1}{19})^2(\frac{37}{38}) + (35+\frac{1}{19})^2(\frac{1}{38}) = 33.207 \\ \sigma &= 5.762\end{align}$$

Comment: What is the expectation, variance and standard deviation for adding up $1000$ independent cases?

Comment: mean = n*E[x] and the variance = n*Var(x) @Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ denote your gain on bet number $i$ for $i=1,2,\dots,1000$. Then, the $X_i$'s are iid with $μ_i:=E[X_i]=-\frac1{19}$ and $σ_i:=\sqrt{33.2133}=5.763$ as you correctly have it. You want to calculate $$\Pr\left(\sum_{i=1}^{1000}X_i>0\right)$$ By the Central limit theorem the distribution of $S:=\sum_{i=1}^{1000}X_i$ is approximately $$S\sim\mathcal N(μ=1000μ_i,σ^2=1000σ_i^2) \implies S\sim\mathcal N(μ=-52.632,σ^2=33213.3)$$ Hence \begin{align}\Pr(S>0)&=\Pr\left(\frac{S-μ}{σ}>\frac{0-(-52.632)}{\sqrt{33213.3}}\right)\\[0.3cm]&=P(Z>0.289)=1-\Phi(0.289)=1-0.613632=0.386368
\end{align}